# AlertDialog doesn't show up after pressing a custom InkWell button with onTap

Tags: flutter

I wanted do make a custom button and call showDialog function. Unfortunately AlertDialog doesn't show up. I tried wrapping InkWell with Material widget, but it didn't help. When I put showDialog in a TextButton onPressed, everything works. Tried using async await, but it didn't work as well. Why doesn't showDialog work in my InkWell button? Tested on Flutter Web and as a Windows App.

**INKWELL BUTTON**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CalendarButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarButton(
      {super.key, required this.onTap, required this.buttonText});

  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final String buttonText;

  @override
  State<CalendarButton> createState() => _CalendarButtonState();
}

class _CalendarButtonState extends State<CalendarButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //utils
    return InkWell(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        widget.onTap;
      },
      child: Ink(
        width: 150,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          color: Colors.grey.shade100,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            widget.buttonText,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AlertDialog**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> showMyDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Create a task'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Confirm'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

FYI InkWell widget is inside SingleChildScrollView.
How it looks in main page file:

```
...
Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.24,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const Calendar(),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
//DOESN'T WORK
                      CalendarButton(
                        onTap: () async {
                          await showMyDialog(context);
                        },
                        buttonText: MainPageText.createCalendarTask,
                      ),
//THIS WORKS
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () async => await showMyDialog(context),
                          child: Text('Presss'))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the brackets, otherwise your onTap will never be called.

```dart
widget.onTap();
```